# Prove il $X_n\to X$ a.s. then it converges in probablility.

Tags: probability

Let $(X_n)$ s.t. $X_n\to X$ almost surely. I want to prove that $X_n\to X$ in probability.

I know that $$\{\omega \mid \lim_{n\to \infty }X_n=X\}\tag{1}$$
$$=\{\omega \mid \forall n\in \mathbb N, \exists m=m(n,\omega ): \forall k\geq m, |X_k(\omega)-X(\omega )|\leq \frac{1}{n}\}.$$

Is this last set equal to $$\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N}\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{k\geq m}\{\omega \mid |X_k(\omega )-X(\omega )|\leq \frac{1}{n}\}\ \ ?\tag{2}$$

The doubt I have is in $(1)$ the $m$ depend on $\omega $ whereas in $(2)$ it doesn't, so I'm a bit confuse and not so sure.

---

If $(1)$ and $(2)$ are indeed equal, then let $\varepsilon >0$
$$1=\mathbb P\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N}\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{k\geq m}\{\omega \mid |X_k(\omega )-X(\omega )|\leq \frac{1}{n}\}\leq \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{k\geq m}\{\omega \mid |X_k(\omega )-X(\omega )|\leq \varepsilon \}\right)=\lim_{m\to \infty }\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{k\geq m}\{|X_n-X|\leq \varepsilon \}\right)\leq \lim_{m\to \infty }\mathbb P(|X_m-X|\leq \varepsilon ),$$

and thus, we get $$\lim_{m\to \infty }\mathbb P(|X_m-X|\leq \varepsilon )=1$$ what prove the claim. Does it work ?

Comment: The result follows immediately from Egorov's theorem, which is proven along the lines of what you wrote (I didn't check carefully).

Comment: @Ian: So if I understand, the equality $(1)=(2)$ is not that obvious, right ?

Comment: @Ian: Acctually, I don't understand why we should use Egorov theorem. The proof I've made is not correct ?

Comment: There is a simple proof using the dominated convergence theorem: fix $\epsilon > 0$ and use $\mathbb{P}(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) = \mathbb{E}{1_{\{ |X_n - X| > \epsilon \} }}$ which goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity by the dominated convergence theorem...

Comment: Your procedure does work actually, the point is that if you define that set as $\bigcap_n A_n$ where $A_n=\bigcup_m B_{n,m}$ then a $\omega$ is in $A_n$ iff it is in $B_{n,m}$ for some $m$. Different $\omega$ indeed have different $m$ values.